# Convert nvarchar ISO-8601 date to datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, type-conversion

hopefully a quick one this.

The below doesn't work:

```
DECLARE @stringDate nvarchar(50)
SET @stringDate = '0001-01-01T12:00:00'

SELECT 
    @stringDate AS StringDate,
    CONVERT(datetime, @stringDate, 126) AS ConvertedDate
```

Produces the error: The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

What's the simplest way of achieving the conversion?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Type `Datetime` does not support the year 0001. Supported range is 1753 to 9999.
As a workaround you can use type `DateTime2` instead

```
SELECT 
    @stringDate AS StringDate,
    CONVERT(datetime2, @stringDate, 126) AS ConvertedDate
```

Comment: The `DATE` or `DATETIME2` data types in SQL Server 2008 **would** support the `01/01/0001` date.....

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't work because for [`DATETIME` data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) the

> Date range [is] January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999.

You have to use the [new data type `DATETIME2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx):

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;  --Not recommended
SET ARITHABORT OFF;     --Not recommended
DECLARE @stringDate nvarchar(50)
SET @stringDate = '0001-01-01T12:00:00'

SELECT 
    @stringDate AS StringDate,
    CONVERT(datetime, @stringDate, 126) AS Converted_DATETIME,
    CONVERT(datetime2, @stringDate, 126) AS Converted_DATETIME2_A,
    CONVERT(datetime2(0), @stringDate, 126) AS Converted_DATETIME2_B
```

Results:

```
StringDate          Converted_DATETIME Converted_DATETIME2_A  Converted_DATETIME2_B
------------------- ------------------ ---------------------- ----------------------
0001-01-01T12:00:00 NULL               0001-01-01 12:00:00.00 0001-01-01 12:00:00
Arithmetic overflow occurred.
```

Note: you may change the default precision for `DATETIME2` data type if your date/time values doesn't have "fractional seconds precision": `DATETIME2(0)`.